# Dynamic Query Selector with own Event Listener

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, queryselector, coingecko

Hi i am using Javascript to Call a API for Pricefeed from Coingecko. I use a Function to add Div's from a button for choosing Coins that will display Prices in different "spaces".

HTML:

```
<button onclick="add_coin('coinspaceA', window.countA); return false;">Add Coin</button>
<button onclick="add_coin('coinspaceB', window.countB); return false;">Add Coin</button>
<button onclick="add_coin('coinspaceC', window.countV); return false;">Add Coin</button>
```

i call the Function fetch_coinlist() before the closing Body Tag

JS:

```
window.countA = 0;
window.countB = 0;
window.countC = 0;

var coins = {};

function fetch_coinlist(){
fetch("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false")
.then(
function(response) {
if (response.status !== 200) {
  alert('Can Not get Price Api! Status: ' +
    response.status);
  return;
}

// Examine the text in the response
response.json().then(function(data) {

coins = {};
for (let i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
  let {id, ...info} = data[i];

  coins[id] = info;
}


});

}
)
.catch(function(err) {
alert('Can Not get Price Api! Status: ' + err);
});
}


function add_coin(space) {

  if (space == "coinspaceA") {

    coinspace(space, window.countA);
  }



  if (space == "coinspaceB") {

    coinspace(space, window.countB);
  }



  if (space == "coinspaceC") {

    coinspace(space, window.countC);

}

}



function coinspace(space, count){



  const div = document.createElement('div');
  count += 1;
  div.id = space + count;


  if (space == "coinspaceA"){
  window.coinspace1 = count;
  }
  if (space == "coinspaceB"){
  window.coinspace2 = count;
  }
  if (space == "coinspaceC"){
  window.coinspace3 = count;
  }

  div.innerHTML = (`

  <input type="button" value="-"  class="curser-del" onclick="remove_coin(this,'` + space + `')"/>

  <select id="` + space + count  + `select" placeholder="Choose Coin"></select>

  <input type="numbers" >

  <label id="` + space + count  + `info">Coins</label>

  `);

  document.getElementById(space).appendChild(div);


  show_coinlist(space, count);


}



function show_coinlist(space, count){



for (let id in coins) {
let item = coins[id];
console.log(item);
const toplist = document.createElement("option");

toplist.value = id;
console.log(toplist.value);

// selector actions
const selector = document.querySelector("#" + space + count + "select");
const info = document.querySelector("#" + space + count + "info");
console.log(selector);
console.log(info);
selector.addEventListener('change', event => {
  info.innerHTML = "Selected item: " + coins[toplist.value].name + " : " + coins[toplist.value].current_price;
});
console.log(coins[toplist.value].name);
console.log(coins[toplist.value].current_price);
toplist.innerHTML = item.symbol.toUpperCase() + " - " + item.name;
console.log(toplist.innerHTML);
console.log(toplist);
document.getElementById("#" + space + count + "select").appendChild(toplist);



}
}
```

When i use the selector on its own with a static ID it works and i get the Price Displayed from the Coin i choose, in the example above it gives me the right Values to the Console but when i try to run the loop it gets aborted after the first cycle with the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

I tryed to put the script at the End of the Site so everything can load, but it does not change the Error, i tryed with static ID this works but i need to have as many selections as the User wants to add, i tryed to put selector Actions outside the loop but it did not work either. When i use console.log(toplist) before ...appendChild(toplist) it gives me the correct option i try to append,

```
<option value="bitcoin">BTC - Bitcoin</option>
```

but the loop stops with the Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Here: `document.getElementById("#" + space + count + "select").appendChild(toplist);` You most likely don't have an id starting with the hash. Remove the hash, or use `.querySelector` instead of `.getElementById`

Comment: FYI: Adding custom properties to `window` and using inline event attributes, like `onclick` are not advisable.

Comment: @Teemu Oh damn thats working! i was trying both with or without but didnt do it that way... thanks for the help!

Comment: @Scott can you tell me why?

Comment: When you add custom properties to `window`, you are adding new Global variables, which is never a good idea because you can wind up overwriting existing properties that you might not be aware of. In all programming languages, declaring variables with the smallest possible scope that meets your needs is recommended.

Comment: As for inline event attributes, that is a 25+ year old legacy technique that has [many drawbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) and doesn't follow modern standards.

Comment: @Scott thanks for the hints i didnt know that!